# Index of children in parent of a specific class

Tags: jquery, children, string-length

A parent container called ".content" contains various children and these children are created dynamically.  I am trying not to do an each loop and compare the children with the one clicked.

This code tells me how many children of the type I have.

```
$(this).parents(".content").children(".r-s, .r-f").length
```

say an example where the above length equals 5, I need to know WHICH in either (0-4 or 1-5) children was selected.

I have been looking at jquery .filter() hoping for an answer, .is() also seems promising.  Any suggestions?

Comment: The one that was clicked would be `this`.   It's not clear what you mean by *either 0-4 or 1-5" (do these relate to `.r-s` / `.r-f`) ?

Comment: Have you tried `.closest`?  Seems it should be `if ($(this).closest(".r-s").length == 0) // then it's in .r-s` but can't tell without your html / what's actually being clicked / what you're trying to find it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [index](https://api.jquery.com/index/) function of jQuery to get the position of the clicked element inside the parent's element. Sth. like this should work:

```
function clickCallback(event) {
  var index = $(".r-s, .r-f").index(event.target);
}
```

Alternatively, if you create the elements dynamically, you could add an attribute to the elements with there respecitve index and then simply access that in your click callback.

```
function clickCallback(event) {
  var index = event.target.getAttribute("customIndex");
}
```

Comment: A user creates them, and I cannot index them like that sadly.   The first method just returns -1.  I even attempted editing it to. $(this).parents(".content").children(".r-s, .r-f").index(e.target))

Comment: Figured something out, this is right.  Thank you for your answer.